# rkhunter found 7 possible rootkits

Tags: ubuntu, security, rkhunter

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.10 and ran *rkhunter* on it. At first it said that there are 4 possible rootkits, but after second check it detected 7. During checking there was everything green and ok, except one warning:

```
 Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments        [ Warning ]
```

But I don't think that this would cause rkhunter's suspicion that there are some rootkits,
would it? Or is it possible that I really got any rootkit even though there was no red "found"
at any of those "known rootkits" check?

There is the output from the last check:

```
System checks summary
=====================

File properties checks...
    Files checked: 149
    Suspect files: 0

Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 479
    Possible rootkits: 7

Applications checks...
    All checks skipped
```

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** I tried to install Fedora instead of Ubuntu and everything seems fine, even that warning is no longer here. So maybe Fedora somehow fixed that warning, thus rkhunter doesn't think that there is any danger whatsoever, not sure.

Comment: You could crosscheck with chkrootkit.

Comment: Regarding your EDIT, could be that both don't use the same database. sudo rkhunter --propupd

Answer (score 0):

" Or is it possible that I really got any rootkit even though there was no red "found" at any of those "known rootkits" check?"

Yes, there are many unknown rootkits...

If it was a clean install from a verified source CD/DVD I would research firmware rootkits.

Good luck mate.

Comment: Is there any utility like _rkhunter_ for detecting firmware rootkits? I've searched but haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't know any utility for detecting firmware rootkits also the information about it is almost non-existent. I would search in DEFCON Conference youtube videos.

Comment: Also visit https://media.ccc.de/search/?q=rootkit